# How to execute an attribute when invoking a method in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, system.reflection

I have a method.

```
[AppAuthorize]
public ActionResult StolenCar(object claimContext)
{
    return View("StolenCar");
}
```

My attribute is code something like this.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class AppAuthorize : Vairs.Presentation.AppAuthorizationAttribute
{
    public bool ConditionalAuthentication
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool requireAuthentication = true;

        if (ConditionalAuthentication)
        {

        }

        if (requireAuthentication)
        {
            var appContext = SecurityContext.Current as SitecoreSecurityContext;

            if (appContext != null)
            {
                appContext.LoginPage =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SecurityPaths.Login];
                appContext.LogoffPage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SecurityPaths.Logout];
            }

            if ((appContext != null) && this.RedirectToLogin && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(appContext.LoginPage))
            {
                appContext.RedirectToLogin = true;
            }

            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run **StolenCar** method dynamically in c#.

```
Type magicType = Type.GetType(controllerFullName);
MethodInfo magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod(actionName);
ConstructorInfo magicConstructor =magicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
object magicClassObject = magicConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { });
var result = magicMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[] { parameters }) as ActionResult;
return result;
```

This way I can invoke **StolenCar** Method but it does not call **AppAuthorize** Attribute. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Just do  `new Class().StolenCar(null)`. attributes are only executed by the MVC framework.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute an attribute". Attributes are mainly used to *indicate* something, they typically don´t have much logic, in particular no business-logic.

Comment: Are you using `AuthorizeAttribute` in `Vairs.Presentation.AppAuthorizationAttribute` class ?

Comment: yes AppAuthorizationAttribute class is extending System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute@stom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from a few built-in system ones, attributes are not magical.

They're simply meta-data, extra information attached to a class, member, etc.

If you want these attributes to be "executed", you will have to do so yourself.

In your context, MVC already does this for you, for the attributes it knows about, but if you start calling these methods yourself then it's on you to discover and process these attributes *if necessary*, nothing in .NET will do it for you automagically.

Comment: Technically, MVC doesn't "execute attributes", it executes filters that happen to be implemented in the same class as attributes (although it executes a *different instance* of the class). If it helps make it less confusing, one could separate the filter and attribute into their own class as in [Passive Attributes](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/).

Comment: Hence why I wrote "executed" in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute` and overriding the `OnActionExecuting` method:

```
public class YourAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);

        //Your code goes here
    }
}
```